# How to run a TCL script to tell run in every 10 minutes?

Tags: tcl, expect

My TCL script:

```
source reboot_patch.tcl

set a 1
while {$a < 10} {
    exec reboot_patch.tcl
    after 60000
    incr a
}
```

I need to run "reboot_patch.tcl" script for every 1 min in my system. I wrote above script. But its running only once and its coming out.

Following is the "reboot_patch.tcl" script:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcl


package require Expect

spawn telnet 40.1.1.2
expect "*console."
send "\r"
expect "*ogin:"
send "test\r"
expect "*word:"
send "test\r"
expect "*>"
send "clear log\r"
expect "*#"
send "commit \r"
expect "*#"
```

Please suggest me a way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Script to print numbers from 1 to 10 in windows 7:

```
#!c:\Tcl\bin\tclsh

set a 1
while { $a < 11} {
puts $a
incr a

}
```

I am unable to run the above script using "./" format in windows7.

Comment: You `source` it first: that means execute it in *this* interpreter, not a spawned one. Does reboot_patch.tcl have an `exit` statement?

Comment: @glenn jackman. I have added my "reboot_patch.tcl" in question. I am not getting the meaning of exit statement. Can you please tell me where should I add this. Thanks.

Comment: Does it give any error messages?

Comment: There is no error message. Simply script is running only once and getting exit.

Answer (score 0):

In general, `exec` command will return the output of program execution. It is our responsibility to capture and print and manipulate it.

You have to print it manually like

```
puts [ exec ./reboot_patch.tcl ]
```

Or like,

```
set result [ exec ./reboot_patch.tcl ]
puts $result
```

Since you are using `exec` without printing it's result, you have not seen anything. Then how come it got executed for the first time ? Who else can do except the following ?

```
source reboot_patch.tcl
```

Well, Since you have sourced the file and it got executed which seemed to be the first time execution but which is not actually from `exec` command.

**Note :** If you are calling any of that sourced file's `proc`, then only it is required to source it. As far as I can see you are not having any proc there. So, source is not required at all.

Comment: Is there any way running script other than "./reboot_patch.tcl". I tried "tclsh reboot_patch.tcl". Its not working.

Comment: Where is the script is located ? Same directory ?

Comment: Its working fine if I run this script in Unix machine. But in windows its not working. I have given shebang line as "#!c:\Tcl\bin\tclsh" and I gave full permission. Its throws "'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." error when I run using "./reboot_patch.tcl". Any clue on this please?

Comment: I have tried in Windows and Unix and working fine for both. Something else might be wrong I guess. Any other input from you ? I am noticing you asking asking some related questions around same area. If you combine them, it will help us yo get the whole picture.

Comment: I am running this "while loop to print 1 to 10 numbers (Program added in Question please see above...)" script in windows7 using ./while.tcl. Its not working. Can you please tell me if there is any mistake in this.