# How to run a tcl script in windows machine using "./script.tcl" format?

Tags: windows, tcl, expect

TCL script :

```
#!c:\Tcl\bin\tclsh

set a 1
while { $a < 11} {
puts $a
incr a

}
```

Its working fine If I run this script as "tclsh script.tcl". But I want to run this script in Windows machine as "./script.tcl". Its throws following error:

```
C:\Users\Balu\Desktop>./script.tcl
 '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

NOTE : This script is working fine in Unix machine, If I run as "./script.tcl".

Please suggest me any ideas to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Windows doesn't understand the `#!` first line syntax at all. That's completely Unix-specific.

To run your script, do something like:

```
C:\Users\Balu\Desktop>  tclsh .\script.tcl
```

If you have an association set up for Tcl script files with `tclsh` in Explorer, you could also run them by appending `;.TCL` to the [`PATHEXT` environment variable](http://environmentvariables.org/PathExt).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to run this script without using tclsh and only with ./ format. To solve the issue asked in question "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420398/how-to-run-a-tcl-script-to-tell-run-in-every-10-minutes". To run a TCL script inside another TCL script in Windows ENV this ./ format is required. Please let me know your ideas to fix this issue.

Comment: Your statements are incorrect. To run another nested tcl script does not require unix specific hashbang support. You can simply use the exec command to run the necessary commands. You cannot run a tcl script without invoking a Tcl interpreter and that comes from tclsh. Even on unix, when the operatin system loader sees an executable file starting with "#!", all it does is run the provided interpreter - in this case 'tclsh'.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux then only `./script.tcl` way will work.
In Windows for running the tcl script you need to run like this `tclsh script.tcl`. Assuming tcl installer has already set the PATH environment variable of System or User Profile. And the `script.tcl` is in the current working directory.

In your case (.) means current working directory.